# Gulp-coffee remove nonexistent files

Tags: javascript, build, coffeescript, gulp, gulp-plugin

I'm using gulp-coffee to compile my coffee files to js, nothing fancy.

I'm having a hard time figuring how to remove js files (in the dest `js` directory) that DO NOT exist anymore in the source `coffee` folder.

I'm quite sure this does not concern directly gulp-coffee, but I'm kind of clueless and I'm not that proficient in gulp.

My Files structure

```
/app/
  /coffee (source)
  /js     (dest)
```

My gulp task

```
gulp.task('coffee', function() {
    return gulp.src('app/coffee/**/*.coffee')
    .pipe($.changed('./app/js/', {extension: '.js'}))
    .pipe($.coffee())
        .on('error', logCoffeeError)
    .pipe(gulp.dest('app/js/'));
});
```

Comment: Why don't you just manually delete all the .js files, then relaunch gulp? It will recompile properly and recreate the relevant files.

Comment: I'm in the middle of creating and deleting multiple files while developing, deleting them manually would break the automation process (for example js injection into index html file)

Comment: Well, if your coffee files get compiled to JS, there's no danger deleting all JS files and just let Gulp rebuild them. Or am I missing something?

Comment: For that matter, you should concatenate and minify everything in one file, and get one script.min.js file. No need for more.

Comment: No, there isn't anything wrong, it's just not automatic and I would do this manually tens of times per day and if I forget to do so I could have injected old files that I do not want

Comment: Your assumption about my dev environment is wrong, I need all the js files because I am in DEV. The min and concat is another build step not relevant here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anybody is interested on the solution of this problem I ended up using this package that does exactly what I was looking for: https://github.com/StevenTheEVILZ/gulp-syncronize

USAGE:

```
gulp.task('unused', function() {
    return syncronize({
        src:    'app/coffee/',  //Source folder
        target: 'app/js/',      //Output folder
        extensions: {
            'js': 'coffee', // Corresponds .js files to the .coffee files; 
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: That's horrific! Just clean and rebuild, that's the safe way to do it.